# Android sticky service is beeing killed loosing all information

Tags: java, android, service, timer

I have service which is basically timer. It receives object with location data, start time, user id etc, and every seconds it increments stop value. I'd like to have this service running non-stop until stopped in application. I've read that i need to start this service as sticky, so i did that. But I've noticed that after my main application is beeing killed by system or user, service restarts and lose all information (about current timers running etc - I have there array with list of objects).

Idea of  that service was that:
user clicks button in app -> service is starting and counting time changing information in notification bar and sending broadcast to main application -> I wish to continue updating notification bar even if app is killed by user or system.

My class below:

```
public class TimerService extends Service{
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    private static JsonHistoryList activities;
    private Intent intent;
    private Handler handler;

    private Runnable sendUpdateToUi = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sendBroadcast();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };

    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals(ACTION_ADD)){
                JsonHistory item = (JsonHistory) intent.getSerializableExtra(HISTORY_ARG);
                new NetworkAsyncTask().execute(ACTION_ADD_ID, item);
            }else if(action.equals(ACTION_DELETE)){
                int id = intent.getIntExtra(CATEGORY_ID_ARG, -1);
                if(id > 0){
                    new NetworkAsyncTask().execute(ACTION_DELETE_ID, id);
                }
            }else if(action.equals(ACTION_CLEAR)){
                activities.clear();
            }
        }
    };

    public TimerService() {
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    private void sendBroadcast() {
        Long time = new Date().getTime();

        for(JsonHistory item: activities){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(History.C_STOP, time);
            String[] selectionArgs = {String.valueOf(item.id)};
            getContentResolver().update(History.URI, values, History.C_ID + "=?", selectionArgs);
            item.stop = time;
        }

        intent.putExtra(ACTIVITY_LIST_ARG, activities);

        Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        bIntent.putExtra(CATEGORY_ARG, activities);
        builder.setContentText(String.format(getString(R.string.notification_bar_message), activities.size()));
        Notification barNotif = builder.build();
        mNotificationManager.notify(SERVICE_ID, barNotif);

        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_ADD);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_DELETE);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_CLEAR);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        intent = new Intent(ACTION);
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdateToUi);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdateToUi, 1000);
        activities = new JsonHistoryList();

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        if(intent != null && intent.hasExtra(TimerService.ACTIVITY_LIST_ARG)){
            ArrayList<JsonHistory> temp = (ArrayList<JsonHistory>) intent.getSerializableExtra(TimerService.ACTIVITY_LIST_ARG);
            if(temp != nu;; && temp.size() > 0)activities.addAll(temp);
        }

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent bIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pbIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, bIntent, 0);
        builder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                        .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText(String.format(getString(R.string.notification_bar_message), activities.size()))
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setOngoing(true)
                        .setContentIntent(pbIntent);
        Notification barNotif = builder.build();
        this.startForeground(SERVICE_ID, barNotif);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdateToUi);
        stopForeground(true);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class NetworkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, String>{
        Gson gson;

        public NetworkAsyncTask() {
            super();
            gson = new Gson();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
            Integer actionId = (Integer) params[0];
            String result = null;
            switch (actionId){
                case ACTION_ADD_ID:
                    break;
                case  ACTION_DELETE_ID:
                    break;
                default:
                    result = null;
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any replies

Comment: " beeing killed " what exactly to you mean?

Comment: service restarts somehow. Notification bar dissapers and apears back with different data.
    private static JsonHistoryList activities; <-- this list is beeing cleared after stopping main app by system or user

Answer (score 0):

When you stop the service it is true it loses its information if the application is destroyed. That is because that instance of the service is tied to that particular instance of the application.

In my opinion, an easy fix would be to store the information you still need in some type of persistent storage (SQLite, Internal/External Memory, Shared Preferences)

Then, every time you start your service with a new application launch just be sure to reload the information you want from whichever persistent storage method you choose.

Also, assuming you don't want this service to continue if the application is killed by the user, be sure to send an intent to the service to stop it like this:

```
    intent = new Intent(this, BackgroundLocationService.class);  
    stopService(intent);
```

Comment: I want to service runs beside application. Main idea is that user is clicking a button, service is starting (timer service with data what was clicked and what time), and I want to preserve information and update notification even main app is not present.

Comment: Does this service ever get stopped? It is generally not good to have a service run even if the user has killed the application that started it.

Comment: Yes service stops if no activities are running. But if any activity is active i'd like to have information about it

Comment: Ok so is your point that if you start your service and then bring the app to the background, you want the service to continue to do its job (Sending notifications after the timer completes). And to clarify the problem is when you background the app, the service is restarting and losing the intent information you gave it?

Comment: Almost exactly. Service continue it's work unless app is killed by user in task manager or by system to preserve memory

Comment: Ok. what method do you use to start the service initially and where does this occur?